# List model Items in a categorized list in view xamarin

Tags: json, xamarin, xamarin.forms

with a Resturent model as below i am retrieving the data to appear in list view as lists with two colomns

the model

```
public class ResturentItems
    {
        [JsonProperty("Resturent")]
        public List<Resturent> Resturent { get; set; }
    }

    public class Resturent : ModelBase
    {
        [JsonIgnore]
        private static readonly ILocalFileToBase64StringConverter _base64Converter = DependencyService.Get<ILocalFileToBase64StringConverter>();

        [JsonProperty("ID")]
        public string ID { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Category")]
        public string Category { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Code")]
        public string Code { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Price")]
        public string Price { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("isservicecharge")]
        public bool isservicecharge { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("isaddonapplicable")]
        public bool isaddonapplicable { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("CostPrice")]
        public string CostPrice { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Date")]
        public string Date { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Image")]
        public string Image { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public ImageSource ImageSource => string.IsNullOrEmpty(Image) ? "userpic.jpg" : ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(_base64Converter.ConvertBack(Image)));

    }
```

and the data retrieve by the below code

```
private List<ResturentPair> GetDishItems(List<Resturent> list)
        {         

            var res = new List<ResturentPair>();
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count-1; i += 2)
            {
                res.Add(new ResturentPair { Item1 = list[i], Item2 = list[i+1] });
            }
            return res;
        }
```

for your convenience i will show below the  model as well

```
public class ResturentPair
    {
        public Resturent Item1 { get; set; }

        public Resturent Item2 { get; set; }
    }
```

so finally the Restaurant details appear with all the details with name and the category , ETC, but my requirement i only want to show the categories ( the Restaurant items list need to be listed as categories, so any idea how to retrieve only to list by only categories of the restaurant items ?? thank you advance for your support

the full code below on the viewmodel

```
public class RootViewModel : ContextViewModelBase
    {
        private readonly IRestService _restService;
        private RootPage _page;

        public RootViewModel(IAppContext context, IRestService restService, IStatusBarService statusBarService) : base(context)
        {
            _restService = restService;
            statusBarService.ShowStatusBar();
            statusBarService.SetDefaultFontColor();
            ActionCommand = new Command(OnActionCommand);
            PageAppearingCommand = new Command<RootPage>(OnPageAppearingCommand);
            PageDisappearingCommand = new Command(OnPageDisappearingCommand);
        }

        public List<ResturentPair> Items { get; set; }

        public List<Resturent> CarouselItems { get; set; }

        public string Photo { get; set; } = "Photo.png";

        public bool IsLoading { get; set; } = true;

        public ICommand ActionCommand { get; }

        public string PagingText { get; set; }

        private async void OnPageAppearingCommand(RootPage page)
        {
            _page = page;
            Photo = $"{DefaultValues.ServerUrl}{Context.User.PhotoUrl}";
            IsLoading = true;
            var items = await _restService.GetFoodMenuInfo();
            CarouselItems = GetCarouselItems(items.Resturent);
            Items = GetDishItems(items.Resturent);
            OnCarouselViewItemSelected(this, new SelectedItemChangedEventArgs(CarouselItems.First())); // we call it for setting paging
            IsLoading = false;
            _page.CarouselView.ItemSelected += OnCarouselViewItemSelected;
        }

        private void OnPageDisappearingCommand()
        {
            _page.CarouselView.ItemSelected -= OnCarouselViewItemSelected;
        }

        private List<Resturent> GetCarouselItems(List<Resturent> items)
        {         

            var carouselViewItems = new List<Resturent>();
            // put your logic here for selecting items for carouselView
            for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                carouselViewItems.Add(items[i]);
            }
            return carouselViewItems;
        }       

        private List<ResturentPair> GetDishItems(List<Resturent> list)
        {         

            var res = new List<ResturentPair>();
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count-1; i += 2)
            {
                res.Add(new ResturentPair { Item1 = list[i], Item2 = list[i+1] });
            }
            return res;
        }


        private void OnCarouselViewItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedIndex = CarouselItems.IndexOf(e.SelectedItem as Resturent);
            var pagingResult = string.Empty;
            for (var i = 0; i < CarouselItems.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i == selectedIndex)
                {
                    pagingResult += $" \uf26d ";
                }
                else
                {
                    pagingResult += $" \uf26c ";
                }
            }
            PagingText = pagingResult;
        }

        private void OnActionCommand()
        {
            Navigator.PushAsync<SettingsViewModel>();
        }
    }
```

below is the sample json out put getting for the API call

```
{
    "Resturent": [
        {
            "ID": "12238000003927",
            "Category": "LEAF TEA_PRE",
            "Name": "LT 100G COP",
            "Code": "80067-012",
            "Description": "LT 100G COP",
            "Price": "140.000",
            "isservicecharge": 0,
            "isaddonapplicable": 0,
            "CostPrice": ".000",
            "Date": "12228000000000",
            "Image": ""
        },
        {
            "ID": "12238000004015",
            "Category": "LEAF TEA_PRE",
            "Name": "LEAF TEA 200g PREMIUM",
            "Code": "80033-024",
            "Description": "LEAF TEA 200g\/24 PREMIUM (PILLOW PACK)",
            "Price": "310.000",
            "isservicecharge": 0,
            "isaddonapplicable": 0,
            "CostPrice": ".000",
            "Date": "12228000000000",
            "Image": ""
        },
        {
            "ID": "12238000006325",
            "Category": "TEA BAGS_PRE",
            "Name": "PREMIUM TAG TBAG 050 ",
            "Code": "80021-024",
            "Description": "TAG TBAG 050\/2.0g\/24 PREMIUM",
            "Price": "240.000",
            "isservicecharge": 0,
            "isaddonapplicable": 0,
            "CostPrice": ".000",
            "Date": "12228000000000",
            "Image": ""
        },
        {
            "ID": "12238000006192",
            "Category": "TEA BAGS_PRE",
            "Name": "TAG TBAG 025 PREMIUM",
            "Code": "80011-012",
            "Description": "TAG TBAG 025\/2.0g\/12 PREMIUM",
            "Price": "125.000",
            "isservicecharge": 0,
            "isaddonapplicable": 0,
            "CostPrice": ".000",
            "Date": "12228000000000",
            "Image": ""
        },
        {
            "ID": "12238000006703",
            "Category": "LEAF TEA_GOU",
            "Name": "TINCADDY 125g EA",
            "Code": "81032-006",
            "Description": "TIN CADDY 125g\/06 ENGLISH AFTERNOON",
            "Price": "450.000",
            "isservicecharge": 0,
            "isaddonapplicable": 0,
            "CostPrice": ".000",
            "Date": "12228000000001",
            "Image": ""
        },
        {
            "ID": "12238000003727",
            "Category": "TEA BAGS_GOU",
            "Name": "FOIL ENV TBAG 025 ENG BFST",
            "Code": "80086-012",
            "Description": "FOIL ENV TBAG 025\/2.0g\/12 ENGLISH BREAKFAST",
            "Price": "160.000",
            "isservicecharge": 0,
            "isaddonapplicable": 0,
            "CostPrice": ".000",
            "Date": "12228000000001",
            "Image": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, can't get if you want to filter restaurants by categories or display a categories carousel. In the last case you have to create an different list of all available categories and read it, instead of reading restaurants.

Comment: @Nick i'm sorry i haven't include the list of items i am expecting to show

Comment: private List<ResturentPair> GetDishItems(List<Resturent> list)
        {            var res = new List<ResturentPair>();
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count-1; i += 2)
            {
                res.Add(new ResturentPair { Item1 = list[i], Item2 = list[i+1] });
            }
            return res;
        }

Comment: and the model related to the ResturentPair is as below

Comment: public class ResturentPair
    {
        public Resturent Item1 { get; set; }

        public Resturent Item2 { get; set; }
    }

Comment: if you want to see the whole code let me know so i can post it another link

Comment: I have have edit the changes and now you can see the above updated question of mine

Comment: @ Nick Kovalsky please let me know if you need further details, thank you

Comment: i feel im not the only one not to understand "my requirement i only want to show the categories", what do you mean by this?

Comment: @ Nick Kovalsky , the meaning of "my requirement i only want to show the categories" i will give you the physical scenario, at the moment i am displaying item names , categories, prices  all together about 450 items on the UI ( which is too much items on the interface and its difficult users to choose items quickly) , so what i need if i arrange the UI (display) to show only items by category it will be around 25 ( less number of items) and users can see the main categories of the menu ( basically categorized items by its menu distinctly, means not repeating the same category twice)

Comment: hope this helps , if you need to see the XAML of the UI page shows the items i can add that too to the question, please let me know, thank you for supporting me

Comment: You mean you want to group items by category in code-behind creating a different list of just around 25 categories?

Comment: Yes Exactly ( what i mentioned as 25 just a number to make it convenient for you to explain my requirement )

Comment: Normally your server must send you the list of categories by a separated api call..

Comment: yes "Resturent : ModelBase" is the model class that i am getting the jason list of items to the app

Comment: @Nick Kovalsky for your consideration i have just added the json output ( from the server i am getting)  for the API call ( please refer the above json output code)

Comment: If you have only data for restaurants and your server doesn't send you list of categories how you want to display categories if you have no names for them, just ids?..

Comment: The categories my server sending me is as you can see the above json output "Category": "LEAF TEA_PRE", "Category": "TEA BAGS_PRE", "Category": "TEA BAGS_GOU", like this , so i want these category names to appear distinctly on the menu page